# Why does the [composer run-script blt-alias] command throw a code 255 error on a Windows machine?

Tags: php, windows, drupal, composer-php

I've been doing my best to follow the instructions at various and sundry locations (such as  [here](http://docs.drupalvm.com/en/latest/getting-started/installation-windows/) [here](https://drupalize.me/videos/installing-vagrant-and-virtualbox?p=1526) [here](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/installing-drupal-vm-on-windows/) [here](https://github.com/Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants/VVV/wiki/Connect-to-Your-Vagrant-Virtual-Machine-with-PuTTY) and [here](http://blt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme/onboarding/)) in order to get composer running on my Windows 7 work machine.

I have no choice but to use this machine at my job for many different reasons. I cannot "just use a Mac or Linux machine".

At any rate, I have done the following:

- Installed vagrant, virtualbox, and drupal vm
- Cloned my site
- Updated my PHP version to 5.6
- Ran: composer install from my site folder

All of this ran successfully. When I execute [composer], I do get the list of options and available commands. However, when I try to run [composer run-script blt-alias] from my site folder, I get the following error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: PWD in C:\drupal_virtualbox\MYSITE\vendor\acquia\blt\bin\blt-robo.php on line 23
Fatal error: Call to undefined function Acquia\Blt\Robo\Inspector\posix_getpwuid() in C:\drupal_virtualbox\MYSITE\vendor\acquia\blt\src\Robo\Inspector\Inspector.php on line 442
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: PWD in C:\drupal_virtualbox\MYSITE\vendor\acquia\blt\bin\blt-robo.php on line 23
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function Acquia\Blt\Robo\Inspector\posix_getpwuid() in C:\drupal_virtualbox\MYSITE\vendor\acquia\blt\src\Robo\Inspector\Inspector.php on line 442
Script blt install-alias -y --ansi handling the blt-alias event returned with error code 255
```

I've looked all over for a solution, but haven't been able to find anything that would resolve this. I'm very new to composer - I've been using Dev Desktop for years, so this is a pretty drastic change. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm facing same error. Did you get any solution to this issue?

Comment: Sorry, Arun. We switched to Docksal. That, in itself, took weeks to configure properly behind our organization's firewall.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that we have some really interesting things going on with our certs here at the office. We had to export our organization's self-signed certs and fold them into babun with the update ca trust command (the folder is c:/Users//.babun/cygwin/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/).

Oddly, in some situations, an environment such as this requires the use of the self-signed cert and other times it will allow the use of default ca-certs. It depends on whether the activity is using wget (self-signed cert) or curl (ca-cert). In the php openssl settings, for example, we have our cafile set to use ca-bundle.crt. Your mileage may vary.

This may also help:
https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2018/installing-php-7-and-composer-on-windows-10